# Export/Import Apex from one database to another database

Tags: oracle, database-migration, oracle-apex

I have two servers,on one server there I have installed apex. Now I want to export Apex from this server and import it to another server...If it is possible then what object should I export/import?

Can you help me ?

Comment: You want to transfer your APEX application or APEX itself? APEX includes Export/Import utilities for deployment.

Comment: Thank you for answer...
I want to export apex itself:D maybe it is a stupid idea,but i wonder if there exists such way.I wanted to avoid installing apex from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need the apex schema clearly.  You'd need the DAD.   I wouldn't be at all surprised to find that there was more.

I think it would be much more straigtforward and reliable to just reinstall apex from the beginning.  It shouldn't be very hard.